# Publishing paid Android app to Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-chrome-arc

I published 8 of my apps earlier in the year with a one-time payment option, without any issues. I have also seen sales come through on the merchant account. Today, when I tried to publish the ninth app, I get the error -

> Up-front payments aren’t supported for ARC apps at this time, but you
>   can still publish your app as free and add consumable products for
>   in-app purchase. We’re working hard to enable support for paid ARC
>   apps, so be sure to check back soon!

Why does it no longer work? Any guesses? I'm trying to get them published soon so they are available for schools to purchase.

Comment: I got the same problem. I published it once as upfront-paid app, but now I can't update it.